# UICollectionView - Section Snapshots - "Failed to find index of item" when removing sections or items

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

I want to create a `collectionView` with dynamic sections that also can be collapsed. This seems to be quite easy with the new `section snapshots` in iOS 14. This is what I have (fully working example).

```swift
import UIKit

enum Section: Hashable {
    case group(Int)
}

enum Item: Hashable {
    case header(Int)
    case item(String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>!

    private var groups = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    private var groupItems: [Int: [String]] = [
        1: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
        2: ["E", "F", "G", "H"],
        3: ["I", "J", "K", "L"],
        4: ["M", "N", "O", "P"],
        5: ["Q", "R", "S", "T"],
    ]
    
    private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        var config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
        config.headerMode = .firstItemInSection
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: config)
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
        
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.frame = view.bounds
        
        configureDataSource()
        applySnapshot()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)) {
            self.groups.remove(at: 0) // This removes the entire first section
            self.applySnapshot()
        }
    }
    
    private func configureDataSource() {
        
        let itemCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String> {
            (cell, indexPath, letter) in
            
            var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            content.text = letter
            cell.contentConfiguration = content

        }
        
        let headerCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Int> {
            (cell, indexPath, number) in
            
            var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            
            content.text = String(number)
            cell.contentConfiguration = content
            
            let headerDisclosureOption = UICellAccessory.OutlineDisclosureOptions(style: .header)
            cell.accessories = [.outlineDisclosure(options: headerDisclosureOption)]
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: { (collectionView, indexPath, item) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            
            switch item {
            case .header(let number):
                return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: headerCellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: number)
            case .item(let letter):
                return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: itemCellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: letter)
            }
        })
    }

    private func applySnapshot() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()

        snapshot.appendSections(groups.map { .group($0) })
        
        // This line causes the error messages. If I comment it out, the messages go away but changing sections (removing or adding some) doesn't work any more (the collectionview does not reflect the changes of the sections)
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
        
        for group in groups {
            var sectionSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<Item>()
            
            // header
            let headerItem = Item.header(group)
            sectionSnapshot.append([headerItem])
            
            // items
            sectionSnapshot.append((groupItems[group] ?? []).map { Item.item($0) }, to: headerItem)
            
            sectionSnapshot.expand([headerItem])
            
            dataSource.apply(sectionSnapshot, to: .group(group))
        }
    }

}
```

It's just a simple collection view showing a few sections with 4 items each. To demonstrate my problem, I've added a closure that is automatically called 2 seconds after loading the view controller. It removes the first section and updates the collectionview's data source.

There's two problems:

First, it gives me these error messages:

```
sectionSnapshotExample[15380:1252802] [DiffableDataSource] Failed to find index of item sectionSnapshotExample.Item.header(1)
sectionSnapshotExample[15380:1252802] [DiffableDataSource] Failed to find index of item sectionSnapshotExample.Item.header(4)
sectionSnapshotExample[15380:1252802] [DiffableDataSource] Failed to find index of item sectionSnapshotExample.Item.header(2)
sectionSnapshotExample[15380:1252802] [DiffableDataSource] Failed to find index of item sectionSnapshotExample.Item.header(3)
sectionSnapshotExample[15380:1252802] [DiffableDataSource] Failed to find index of item sectionSnapshotExample.Item.header(5)
```

Secondly, the update is visually not nice because it reloads the entire collection view (all cells are crossfading to themselves, even though they haven't changed).

The error is caused inside the `applySnapshot()` method:

```swift
private func applySnapshot() {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()

    snapshot.appendSections(groups.map { .group($0) })
    

    // This line causes the error messages
    dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    
    ....
}
```

This applies the sections to the data source (Apple is doing the same in their example projects).

If I comment this line out, then the sections aren't updated anymore (in this example, the deleted section would stay in the collection view.

Any ideas? Am I doing it wrong? Are `section snapshots` not meant to be used with dynamic content? If so, is there another simple way to have collapsible sections?

Thanks!

Comment: I think an error "[DiffableDataSource] Failed to find index of item" is caused by line "sectionSnapshot.expand([headerItem])". 
I have a similar problem and without expanding the section I am not getting this error.

The problem with animations is still present - all cells reload.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: @Anthony I found a solution

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue earlier today, and this post was the only reference to it that I could find anywhere on the internet.

After a few hours of tinkering I figured out a fix. It seems that `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` has problems with automatic diffing when you try to expand headers for pre-existing sections while applying a snapshot with new content.

So instead of letting it always calculate the diff fully automatically by creating a new top level snapshot with no content, you need to instead have your data source generate a snapshot, check if the sections you're adding content to already exist in the snapshot, and then only apply a new top level snapshot if there's missing sections.

In practice, this looks like going from this…

```
func applySnapshot(with cheeses: [Cheese]?) {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<CheeseType, ListItem>()

    snapshot.appendSections(CheeseType.allCases)
    dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
    
    for cheeseType in CheeseType.allCases {
        var sectionSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<ListItem>()
        
        let header = ListItem.header(cheeseType)
        sectionSnapshot.append([header])
        sectionSnapshot.expand([header])
        
        if let cheeses = cheeses {
            let matchingCheese = cheeses.filter { $0.cheeseType == cheeseType }
            let cheeseItems = matchingCheese.map { ListItem.content($0) }
            sectionSnapshot.append(cheeseItems, to: header)
        }
        
        dataSource?.apply(sectionSnapshot, to: cheeseType)
    }
}
```

…to something like this.

```
func applySnapshot(with cheeses: [Cheese]?) {
    /* Instead of creating a blank snapshot every time,
       source a snapshot from dataSource if possible and
       only create a blank snapshot if that's not possible */
    var snapshot = dataSource?.snapshot() ?? NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<CheeseType, ListItem>()

    /* Need to prevent sections that already exist in
       the snapshot from being added again.
       In this case, checking if sectionIdentifiers is
       empty is adequate since sections never change -
       other cases may need more involved checking */
    if snapshot.sectionIdentifiers.isEmpty {
        snapshot.appendSections(CheeseType.allCases)
        dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
    }
    
    for cheeseType in CheeseType.allCases {
        var sectionSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<ListItem>()
        
        let header = ListItem.header(cheeseType)
        sectionSnapshot.append([header])
        sectionSnapshot.expand([header])
        
        if let cheeses = cheeses {
            let matchingCheese = cheeses.filter { $0.cheeseType == cheeseType }
            let cheeseItems = matchingCheese.map { ListItem.content($0) }
            sectionSnapshot.append(cheeseItems, to: header)
        }
        
        dataSource?.apply(sectionSnapshot, to: cheeseType)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and my solution was:

> ```
>     var collapseSectionSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<CollapsibleElementType>()
>     elements.forEach { collapseHeader in
>         let item = CollapsibleElementType.header(collapseHeader)
>         collapseSectionSnapshot.append([item])
>         let collpasibleElement = collapseHeader.collapsibleElements.map({CollapsibleElementType.element($0)})
>         collapseSectionSnapshot.append(collpasibleElement, to: item)
>     }
>     dataSource.apply(collapseSectionSnapshot, to: .main, animatingDifferences: false)
> ```

I don't create NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot I only use the above code.